# How to take multiple rows in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, row

is there a method to get multiple rows in a JTable object? I usually take a row using `getSelectedRow()`, but this works with a single row. What I want is to take all the rows that I select and after save them in a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `getSelectedRows()` in `JTable` to get multiple selected rows.